# Which format should be more smooth for complex R8 textures - BC4 or BC7?

Tags: windows, directx, textures, texture2d

**Hello,**

In my DX project I build textures. The question is about bitmap fonts (**channel R8** only).
It looks like the **BC7** is more smooth (but I am not sure), than the **BC4**.
What is the suggestion, which block compression is better for such monochrome textures?
I am asking only about the DDS quality, not about efficiency.

*Thank you*